# Integrate dynamic s3 (for storing wp-content folder), SQL database and WordPress in Swisscom Application Cloud

Tags: wordpress, storage, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

Currently WordPress and MySQL instance running on Swisscom cloud. But last week suddenly wp-content, Was deleted and not able to running website properly because of content missing. After that I communicated with Swisscom and they have explained problem and possible solution. They have suggested to use external service for storing content media file and other document. But I don't have any idea how to do it.

If somebody has solved the same problem then please provide your solution or give some suggestion.

Comment: Apps deployed to CF should *never* write important information to the local file system.  It's ephemeral and that info will be lost.  There are Wordpress plugins that will allow you to store data on S3.  Sorry I can't recommend one, but if you search the Wordpress plugin site for "S3" you can easily find them.

Comment: Thank you for your time and interest. yes, thats i understood, but now i am looking some solution to integrate directly (without plugings) wordpress with swisscom s3 dynamic storage.

Answer (score 1):

here the official answer from Swisscom's Product Management:

> We do not offically support Wordpress on the Application Cloud. There
>   are many examples of how to deploy Wordpress on Cloud Foundry are
>   available, but they are only applicable to certain configurations. To
>   our best knowlege there is no valid, generic solution that is
>   applicable to every wordpress installation and configuration.
>   Therefore we do not officialy support it. The issues exist in in the
>   area of file system (Wordpress Requires non ephemeral files system to
>   work) and in awareness of Wordpress and its plugins the they  may be
>   running in multiple instances (in case of the horizontal scaling)

Answer (score 0):

EDITED VERSION:

This solution is not suitable for a production deployment of wordpress to the Cloud since the ephemeral filesystem is causing data loss anytime the application is restarted or staged. This can happen anytime. Another issue could be the horizontal scaling of the application with multiple instances all with different ephemeral filesystems not synchronized. For this reason this solution cannot be used for production.

This is due to the architecture of Wordpress that is NOT ready at the moment for a Cloud environment and not to the Cloud itself. Applications deployed to the Cloud should respect the [twelve-factor app rules](https://12factor.net/).

This small howto could be used instead for blogs and all the situation where a backup is enough and NO more than one instance is required.

I tried to make a basic installation of wordpress on the Swisscom Cloud.
First of all I downloaded the code of wordpress. It should be present a file named "wp-config-sample.php". Rename it to "wp-config.php" and substitute the following lines on the file:

```
// ** Read MySQL service properties from _ENV['VCAP_SERVICES']
$services = json_decode($_ENV['VCAP_SERVICES'], true);
$service = $services['mariadb'][0];  // pick the first MySQL service

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', $service['credentials']['database']);

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', $service['credentials']['username']);

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', $service['credentials']['password']);

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', $service['credentials']['host'] . ':' .      $service['credentials']['port']);

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

These lines allows wordpress to grab the database credentials from the environment variables. In this specific case the variables keys point to the Swisscom mariadb service. In case the app restarts these information will be automatically available to the app.

Make sure to create a mariadb and bind it to the application. This can be done in different ways and at different stages of the deployment.

To execute periodically backups of the application media, I installed a plugin to make a backup to compatible S3 storages. The Swisscom dynamic storage service is a S3 compatible storage and you can use this service together with the plugin [updraftplus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/). So first I installed the plugin using the wordpress plugin manager.
Then I created a dynamic storage service that I attached to the application. After the restaging of the application you can use the Cloud Foundry cli to list the environment variables of the application:

```
    cf env appName
```

and you should get something like this:

```
       {
"VCAP_SERVICES": {
  "dynstrg": [
   {
    "credentials": {
     "accessHost": "ds31s3.swisscom.com",
     "accessKey": "key",
     "sharedSecret": "secret"
    },
    "label": "dynstrg",
    "name": "test-ivan-dynstrg",
    "plan": "usage",
    "provider": null,
    "syslog_drain_url": null,
    "tags": [],
    "volume_mounts": []
   }
  ],
  "mariadb": [
   {
    "credentials": {
     "database": "database",
     "database_uri": "mysql://uri",
     "host": "10.0.20.18",
     "jdbcUrl": "jdbc:mysql://uri",
     "name": "name",
     "password": "pass",
     "port": 3306,
     "uri": "uri",
     "username": "user"
    },
    "label": "mariadb",
    "name": "test-ivan-mariadb",
    "plan": "small",
    "provider": null,
    "syslog_drain_url": null,
    "tags": [],
    "volume_mounts": []
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Keep note of the "accessHost", "accessKey", and "sharedSecret".

At this point you need to create a bucket on the dynamic storage. You can do this with different types of applications.
This step is very important. Without a bucket the plugin doesn't work.

Once you created your bucket keep note of the name of it.

Now you can configure the "updraftplus" plugin:
You need to choose S3 compatible (generic) service and enter the accessHost in the S3 end-point field, the accessKey in the S3 access key, the sharedSecret in the S3 secret key, and the name of the bucket in the field S3 location.
This should configure correctly the plugin. Now you can backup both files than database.

Keep in mind that when the app restarts the plugin will be not anymore installed (it was installed on the ephemeral filesystem) so you need to re-install it and to execute the restore process after.

This solution can still cause data loss. Backups can be older than the crash or restart of the application.

But for the use case of a personal blog can be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Now i am trying to take backup using UpdraftPlus pluging to Swisscom s3 dynamic storage, but it will always show "creating file backup zips" in prograss notification.  is there any configuration file available to storage wp-content in s3 dynamic storage?

Comment: Did the configuration went well? In the settings there is the button "test S3 settings". In case of error it gives some information about the problem. I would like to add that the UpdraftPlus solution can still lead to data loss, in case the app restarts and the backup was not performed recently. Another possible solution would involve the use of an external server where to store the data files as mentioned  [here](https://www.cloudfoundry.org/100-day-challenge-062-running-wordpress-on-cloud-foundry/) and [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/cf-ex-wordpress) using a ssh connection.

Comment: 'test s3 setting' works fine, but after that when started taking backup and it is just retrying after few min but never end. i know both this link, but currently i don't have any external server where i can store data files. why we can not store data file to S3 directly?

Comment: To be able to store data file directly to S3you need to install a plugin, or modify the application (wordpress itself) in order to use libraries like s3fs and fuse, etc. In general, an application deployed to the cloud has an ephemeral filesystem. This means that important data should not be stored in the filesystem. This [link](https://12factor.net/) provides information on how an app should be.

Comment: I edited the first answer. I am sorry that this cannot be used in your specific use case, but for other cases like personal blogs etc.. this example can be used.